# DLL load failed, DLLs not in right location

Tags: python, dll, installation, pygame, importerror

I have `pygame` 1.9.2 for Python 3.2+. However, when I try to start up Python with `pygame`, I receive: `"ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."` I found the files it needs, but where should I put them?

This is my full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\hg.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: this more than likely indicates you installed python wrong... python comes prebundled with tkinter which is the only dll i think pygame needs (although i could be wrong)...

Comment: I had that problem a while back...think I fixed it by running `pip install pygame` at an OS command prompt instead of running the installer.

Comment: How do I pip install pygame? I am using Windows 10. @martineau

Comment: Max: Sorry, I don't know exactly since I'm running Windows 7—but I assume it would be the same way. When trying to run `pip`, it's important that the OS can find the executable. In Python 2 and 3 it's in the `C:\PythonXX\Scripts` directory (even though technically it's not a "script"), so that should be your current directory at the command line prompt or the directory name should be added to your `PATH` enviroment variable first (the latter is what I've done).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most pygame errors in windows 10 are caused by having an out-of-date pygame by installing the compiled .exe version while not installing it from the official source, since their version is different from the PyPi index.

You will have to download the corresponding file suitable for your system from here:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Then do

```
pip install c:/path/to/the/wheelfile.whl
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly! You don't know how long I tried to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

You must have installed `pygame` incorrectly or something went wrong during installation. I would uninstall `pygame` and reinstall it with the `pip` command.

Go to the search bar at the bottom left of your desktop (on your taskbar) and enter `cmd`. This will open the command line interface (CLI). Then go to here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ and install the file `get-pip.py`. Once this has been completed, go to the `cmd` you opened earlier and enter `python get-pip.py`. This should install `pip`, `setuptools` and `wheel`.

After this, use the command below to install `pygame`:

```
pip install pygame
```

Then try a simple test to see if it works:

```
import pygame
print(pygame)
```

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to pip install pygame.

Comment: @MaximoMaxosaur i've edited my answer to explain how to install `pip`.

Comment: I have installed pygame through pip, but I still am encountering this problem. What should I do?

Comment: @Maximo Maxosaur If it won't install through pip, try the source .exe from the official website, and if that fails, try installing it directly from the Python Package Index (PyPI).